# [NGINX]Can't get proxy_pass and robots.txt to work

Tags: nginx, robots.txt

I'm running Kibana behind NGINX and I want to add a robots.txt. I added robots.txt to /var/www/example.com but no matter what I try, when I access example.com/robots.txt it redirects to Kibana.

```
server {

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

location = /robots.txt {
    root /var/www/example.com/;
}

location / {

  if ($request_uri ~* "^/robots.txt") {
    rewrite ^/robots.txt /robots.txt last;
  }

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

~

}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
```

under location /

```
location = /robots.txt {
    alias /var/www/example/com/html/robots.txt ;
}
```

under server.

The closest I can get is with the root one, which will redirect example.com/robots.txt to example.com/var/www/example.com/html/robots.txt.

Comment: Is the file at `/var/www/example/com/html/robots.txt` or `/var/www/example/com/robots.txt` or `/var/www/example.com/html/robots.txt`?

Comment: The full path on the server is `/var/www/example.com/html/robots.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the path of `/robots.txt` is `/var/www/example.com/html/robots.txt`, use:

```
server {
    ...

    location = /robots.txt {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
    }

    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

The exact match `location` block will always take precedence. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Also thanks for the link to the documentation, that cleared some things up as well. I did not find that page before.